Mid to late 80s/Early 90s movie about a guy killing vampires
I know that the title doesn't give enough info but I am trying to find a movie that was shown on the Sci Fi channel (SyFy) back in the mid-2000s. 
One of the scenes that I remember was a guy and a female in a building staking vampires while they were sleeping in their caskets. The guy was about to stake the last vampire in it's casket before it started to attack him and when he finally staked her he asked where the head vampire was. 
She said that he was right behind him, the head vampire was standing there with the female and shown that he had already bit her. 
I don't remember too much about what happened to the head vampire but I know that the building was collapsing and he tried to get the female, but he couldn't get to her in time. 
The last thing I do remember about the movie was that the guy was in a mental institution and he happen to stake a vampire that was going after him. 
The main character had brown hair with a either a stubble beard or short beard. The vampires looked human where I think the head vampire had a creature-like appearance. That's all I can recall from it.

This sounds really familiar to me, but I can't quite put my finger on it.  Is there anything else you can remember?  Physical appearance of any of the actors?  Maybe a distinctive building?  Did the vampires have any unique appearance (other than fangs, obviously)?

The main character had brown hair with a either a stubble beard or short beard. The vampires looked human where I think the head vampire had a creature-like appearance.

You're looking for Out For Blood, though it actually is from the mid-00s (2004).

In Los Angeles, Detective Hank Holten is obsessed by his ex-wife, the writer of vampire novels Susan Hastings, stalking her and having drinking problems. His chief and friend, Captain John Billings, makes him promise to forget her and stop drinking, and assigns Hank to find Layla Simmons, who is missing and without notice to her family. Hank goes to a rave party, finds Layla, they go to an orgy party in an old building, and while having sex with her, Hank finds that the place is a vampire nest. He is bitten by the vampire-leader, but nobody believes on him. He looks for Susan to help him. 

The movie's prologue and epilogue take place in a psychiatric hospital where Hank currently resides, and in the end he stakes his ex in his cell. And before that:

After searching a few empty rooms, Hank found the coffins and staked all the vampires. Just as the sun went down, he came upon two more coffins, one belonging to Alex and the other to Layla, who were just waking up. After complimenting Alex on his shirt, Hank destroyed him with a crossbow. Layla leapt at Hank, and Hank shoved a stake through her heart. But where was the Master? "Right behind you," said Layla, with her dying unbreath. Hank turned to see both the Master and Susan standing there. Susan's neck revealed that she had been bitten.

It starred Kevin Dillon in the lead role and Lance Henriksen. Here's a clip:




Well, I haven't seen that one, so I guess my memory was playing tricks on me. :)

Yes, that's the movie. I find it funny that I didn't realize that it was made in 2004. Then again, it has been at least 10 years since I seen it.
